# focus-follows-mouse with [some] java applications doesn't behave as expected

Tags: java, windows, focus, autofocus

Environment: Windows 7, JRE 8.65, observed with both yEd 3.14 and GanttProject 2.7.1 (also previously observed on Win XP.)

Can the program's main window take focus (not auto-raise) without being atop other windows and without clicking in it? (nothing found in 917 results from a StackOverflow search on the words "Java" "window" and "focus", though I was getting bleary-eyed by the end.)

The problem is that when I move the pointer into or across the program's window, that window does not activate, though it activates the icon in the "task bar" (which is auto-hidden.) It is clear that the program recognises the pointer's existence and focus change, but the main window never actually takes the pointer (i.e. the main window remains inactive, and requires that I click in it to activate it; which raises it, which is exactly the behaviour I try to avoid with F-F-M.)

This is more troublesome because when the icon in the task bar activates, the task bar covers a chunk of my screen and won't go away until the main program window is activated by clicking in it. Simply moving the mouse from one place to another on the screen has about a 30% probability of touching (and half-activating) one of these program windows, forcing me to locate the window, click in it, minimise it, then get back to what I really was trying to do. (Yes, my "desktop" is a jumble, but everything has its place and normally I can rapidly navigate among the dozen or so windows that are truly useful.)

Thanks for any pointers or advice. (Though suggestions that I change my behaviour probably won't be followed.)

Answer (score -1):

This problem occurred to me as well. The only workaround I got so far is using JRE 6 if possible since this annoying behavior started with JRE 7.

Comment: It seems the strange behavior only occurres if there is more than one JFrame displayed. I used Oracle's demo code to check which events are fired [docs.oracle.com/.../WindowEventDemo.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/events/WindowEventDemoProject/src/events/WindowEventDemo.java).  
If there is only one window everything works as expected. If I run a second instance of the WindowEventDemo-Class none of the windows gets the focus right although the "windowActivated"- and "windowGainedFocus"-events ar fired everytime.

Comment: I am actually using JRE 8 (as noted in the original post). There may be changes version-to-version, but going back to 7 is not in the cards.